# I want to migrate off CodeIgniter for security reasons

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, xss

I have a website written in PHP with the CodeIgniter framework. It's been a work in progress for a few years now, and I eventually want to open-source it. It currently runs to about 10k lines of PHP (not including CodeIgniter libraries). It has become clear to me recently that I can't keep using CodeIgniter.

The main issue with it is that it seems like the developers either don't understand XSS and proper escaping, or they don't care. Even arguments to functions that end up directly in attributes (e.g., `anchor()`) aren't escaped. Functions that generate form inputs are inconsistent regarding whether they escape and the documentation is silent on this topic (all I can do is read the source code). And the "templating engine", if it can even be called that, doesn't escape either, which makes it basically useless. I'm tired of writing `<?=anchor(html_escape('foo/bar/' . rawurlencode($baz)), html_escape($baz))?>` every time I want to output a link. It makes the code ugly as hell and I'm sure I missed a few places. In some cases inputs are inappropriately "sanitized" and this behaviour can't be turned off; for example, if the user enters a string containing `%10` in any form input field, that substring is removed before the application gets to see it.

My code relies on a number of CodeIgniter libraries, including Database (active record pattern), Email, Form validation, Pagination, and Session.

What is another PHP framework which:

- is based on the MVC pattern;
- has a proper templating engine and doesn't suck at escaping things;
- is relatively easy to transition to from CodeIgniter (has most of the same libraries)

?

Comment: Why don't you do what I did and extend the CI classes in question so they do what you do? I didn't like the whole blacklist XSS approach they were using so I extended the core Security class with my own MY_Security.php class and made a whitelist sanitation instead. The same can be done for all the classes, it's fairly simple to do and can then be dropped into any application folder to override the default methods.

Comment: It seems to me that this would require rewriting large portions of the CI libraries, and if I'm going to do that then I might as well just use a different framework.

Answer (score 1):

There's tons of MVC Frameworks out there. I personally use [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) myself. It's a framework you can extend as you wan't without the need of useless libraries. Others to consider are [Lithium](http://li3.me/) and [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)

The userbase on Symfony is larger than the others, but they're all pretty much solid. You can use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) with the frameworks to extend with third-party libraries aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [`CakePHP`](http://cakephp.org) it was based on Rails principles and should be fast and enough to rewrite your application without too much hassle.

Anyway, the `Zend Framework` should be a cool alternative.